# Call Node JS javascript from C++

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js

Is there a way to call Node JS javascript from C++? Any prewritten library?
For C# we have sockets etc but do we have any existing solution? We tried Edge.js but it is there for an older node and probably not maintained.

We need to integrate this solution in a legacy desktop C++ application

Any help? please

Comment: Does the call have to be from C++ to Node or from Node to C++?

Comment: You can run a node.js program from your C++ app and get the result or have it start a server which you then communicate with or you can use stdio and stdout to feed data and get results.  It's not really clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Take a look at nodejs c++ addon: https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html

Comment: @pergy - The nodejs add-on is for doing C++ add-ons to node.js so a node.js program (that is the central process), can then execute C/C++ code as part of its process.  It doesn't sound like that's what the OP is asking for (though it is not entirely clear).

Comment: We have a deskttop C++ application and we need to and fro calling from node to C++

Comment: in c++ add on for Node the starter is javascript we want the caller to be c++

Comment: we have a legacy c++ app , we have a javascript code which does some processing, but the main app or host or calling dlll has to be in c++, which should call javascript. this is the requirement

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: no we ported the app